Why is the compile_commands.json file not generating when I build a project using CMake?
I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline in gitlab that builds my project in the first stage and uses clang-tidy to run static analysis in the second stage. I soon realized that clang-tidy uses the compile_commands.json file (which is generated during build if CMake is used). I shifted gears to create a pipeline for the open-source project "Iceoryx" as they have all the necessary files (CMakeLists.txt, .clangtidy, etc.) already in the project and well documented. However, even though I am able to build and compile the Iceoryx project successfully, there is no compile_commands.json file being generated.
I am currently trying to build the project locally (without the pipeline) to see if compile_commands.json file is generated that way but have not had luck so far. I have included the directions I am following and the commands I am using at the moment. Would love some guidance as to what I might be doing wrong that is causing the compile_commands.json file to not generate.
Directions (Windows) for project setup from the Iceoryx github repo:
https://github.com/eclipse-iceoryx/iceoryx/blob/main/doc/website/getting-started/installation.md
Build Commands:
cmake -Bbuild -Hiceoryx_meta -DBUILD_TEST=ON -DINTROSPECTION=OFF -DBINDING_C=ON -DEXAMPLES=ON -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON

cmake --build build -j 4


Which CMake generator do you use when configure the project? According to the documentation, the option CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS works only for Makefile and Ninja generators. E.g. it won't work for Visual Studio being used as a generator.

Ah I see that now, I was able to use the MinGW Makefile generator to build the project and that did generate a compile_commands.json file. Thank you so much!

Resolved: Based of the comment above, I realized that the compile_commands.json file can only be generated for Makefile ad Ninja generator. I then proceeded to use the MinGW Makefile generator and was able to successfully build and generate the necessary files!

Note this answer of mine covering this very use case which doesn't require the installation of MinGW.
